# SSh: Access Denied, Windows 10

Tags: ssh, password, remote-access, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to Linux in general but also even newer to the Window's 10 Ubuntu subsystem.  I've been trying to set up ssh and so I set up a static ip address and logged into my router and forwarded port 22 as per usual. Using my public ip, I found a site that I was able to plug that into and the site confirmed that port 22 had indeed been forwarded.

After that I followed the instructions on the link https://superuser.com/questions/1111591/how-can-i-ssh-into-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10
and installed openssh-server, added my username and set up my sshd_config file as such:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation no

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers username
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for    
RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

After setting up open ssh I tried using PuTTY to login to my server using my public IP as the address, myusername as the user and the user's password as the password and it gives me a

```
Access Denied
```

error message.  I'm positive that I'm using the right password for that user name. Why am I still being denied access?  If any of you can spot something amiss or maybe a step I missed, your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What do ssh's logs report?

Comment: I've tried to look for the /var/log/auth.log and I'm told that there is No such file or directory

Comment: Are you running your wsl elevated ?

Comment: You cannot run WSL "elevated". It is a kernel-level component. Can you tell us your Windows 10 build number? Before a certain build, it was impossible to connect to network reliably from inside WSL instance.

Comment: Probably you should open port 22 in your Windows Firewall: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-3114787/open-firewall-ports-windows.html

Comment: Late reply, I know (Community-bot bumped the question today), but if the port wasn't open, the OP wouldn't be able to enter the username and password at all.  They would have received a "Connection refused" before even being offered the prompt, not an "Access denied" after entering the name/pw.